# How and for how long do browsers store Etags?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, etag

I wish to implement `ETag` based `cache-control`, and I am wondering how long `ETags` are stored in a browser and if they can be kept for longer than the current session.

I have the server setting and sending `ETags` for responses correctly, and I am sending requests from the browser with `jQuery.ajax`.

The system works correctly, responding with the appropriate *304 response* if the `Not-Modified` header (previous `ETag`) matches the generated `ETag` on the server. This all works fine for the current session, however when I close the browser and reopen it, the `Not-Modified` header is not being sent by jQuery any more.

I am wondering if there are any methods I could use to trigger the default browser behaviour, and send the `Not-Modified` header for responses (if applicable), **without** manually setting the header in the ajax request or storing the `ETag` in `localStorage`/`indexedDb`.

Comment: if an `etag` is not sent properly after a session is closed, perhaps you are not sending the right `expires` headers.

Comment: Do you clear the cache on close of the window? The `ETag` is stored with the file in cache. So if the browser clears the elements out of cache the `ETag` also is lost. However if the file is still in cache the browser sends the `ETag` with the request to tell the server that there is already a file with that `ETag` in cache.

Answer (score 2):

An Etag must be accompanied by other tags that tell the browser how long to hold the content

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching?csw=1#LeverageBrowserCaching

*It is important to specify one of Expires or Cache-Control max-age, and one of Last-Modified or ETag, for all cacheable resources. It is redundant to specify both Expires and Cache-Control: max-age, or to specify both Last-Modified and ETag.*

So it all depends on the duration you specify with the Expires or max-age tag on how long the browser will hold it

The only purpose of the etag is so that the browser can issue a "if modified" request after the initial expiration period to see if the content has actually changed or gets back a 304 not modified.

Badly managed 304's can cause other problems, like unnecessary and redundant 304 requests: http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/easy-cache-headers/

Comment: Thanks for the resources, came in handy to verify if I set the headers right. As it turns out, my issue was caused by Chrome not caching files with self signed certificates on `https` connections.